# Errors fetching records within a month

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having issues trying to fetch records for dates within a month. The records usually stops at the penultimate day.  If for example, I try to select records between October 1 and 31, I only get records ending at October 30. Same thing applies to August, records stop at August 29.
This is a snippet

```
SELECT * FROM transactions where date BETWEEN date(CONCAT('2017', '-', '08','-01')) AND date(CONCAT('2017', '-', '08','-30')
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `date` column likely has a time portion, which means that 2017-08-30 is being translated as midnight (00:00:00.000) of that day, so anything later in that day will be outside of the range. You're probably better off using `date >= 2017-08-01 and date < 2017-09-01`. Using `BETWEEN` with datetime values can be tricky.

Comment: No it has to be  between 2017-08-01 and  2017-08-30. That date options are gotten from a form so we have to make the code dynamic.

Comment: Try rereading what I wrote and think about how the keyword `BETWEEN` works.

Comment: use brackets around `[date]` because date is a reserved word

Answer (score -1):

try using YEAR() and MONTH():

```
 SELECT * FROM transactions 
 WHERE YEAR([date]) = 2017 AND MONTH([date]) = 8
```

Comment: One potential issue with this approach is that it can't use indexes on the date column.

Comment: This answer does not address 'BETWEEN'